# How to load a sub-application from a main application in Flex

Tags: php, mysql, apache-flex, web-applications, program-entry-point

I've created a client with login acces in Flex. After the succesful login i have to show a table based on a mySQL server. The database is composed by some tables, and I have created 6 flex mxml components with each own scripts for each of those tables. How can i load sub-applications, for example with a PopUpButton or a TabBar in the main application?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you would do well to wrap your components in [modules](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=modular_2.html), and load them either when your ViewStack (controller by PopUpButton or TabBar) changes, or pre-load them while the the user is entering their login details.

You can have great control of loading a module, and when it's loaded fire an event to ask for login credentials or watch for the module loaded event and fire off an event with login credentials and anything else that might be needed by the module (and it's components) once loaded.

Comment: the problem is to use the "Create Application from Database" tool which automatically converts the mxml module into mxml application.
Anyway your answer is very useful. Thanks